# Flutter - ListView inside Card

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to create a ListView in a Card. I want to add/remoove items out of the ListView while the app is running.
I tried this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.devices,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
        ),
        leading: Image.asset(
            "assets/logos/logo_standalone.png"
        ),
      ),

      body: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
        ),

        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const ListTile(title: Text("Test"));
            },
            itemCount: 5,
            shrinkWrap: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I run that there are many errors. Is there any possibillity to do that?

Comment: You can use card widget and use other widgets inside it as per your ui, And coming to the add remove functionality you can use Gesturedetector as a parent for Card widget and add/remove the item from the list using the onTap function. then just use the set state method to get the updated state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `ListView` you need the define size of the child regarding the scroll direction. If you are using `Axis.horizontal` the child should have a width property. If you are using `Axis.vertical`, then the child should have a height property.

Also, Expanded is used inside a `Column`, `Row`, or `Flex`. You can use `SizedBox.expand` for an expanded container.

Read about that at here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout

So instead of:

```dart
child: Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return const ListTile(title: Text("Test"));
    },
    itemCount: 5,
    shrinkWrap: true,
  ),
),
```

You should do this:

```dart
child: SizedBox.expand(
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 5,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
        child: const ListTile(
          title: Text("Test"),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Is it possible that the card gets bigger the more items are in the list?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you have a vertical `ListView`, you don't need a `SizedBox.expanded` above. You can add `shrinkWrap: true` to the `ListView` and give a `height` property to the child. The card size will grow as the itemCount * child's size.

Comment: Worked. Thanks, my hero! xD